# Strptime my table gives me NA

Tags: r, linux

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", header = F, sep = '\t')
```

This is my table that I read from my csv file

```
                           V1 
1 Tue Feb 11 12:19:39  0 2014
2 Tue Feb 11 12:19:56  0 2014
3 Tue Feb 11 12:20:04  0 2014
4 Tue Feb 11 12:21:06  0 2014
5 Tue Feb 11 12:21:15  0 2014
6 Tue Feb 11 12:21:30  0 2014
```

I'm using this code to strptime the table

```
df1 = strptime(df, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

My results are:

```
               V1 
NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I dont get what I'm doing wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: `strptime` works on strings, not data frames. You'll need to either concatenate the columns into a string and then use `strptime`, or use another formative function that takes individual components (of which I do not use or know at the moment ...).

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do... are you trying to convert the columns to date-time objects (e.g. POSIXlt or POSIXct)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you have a `data.frame` (`df1`) with a single column named `V1`, which is a vector of strings. (Your first example was unclear on this.)

Unfortunately, `strptime` is a bit strict on its understanding of "offsets". Specifically, it wants its offset in hours/minutes, so your `0` (I'm assuming that that is offset) should be `-0000` or `+0000`. You can automate that with something like:

```
gsub(" 0 ", " -0000 ", df1$V1)
```

From there, your format string should work fine:

```
strptime(gsub(" 0 ", " -0000 ", df1$V1),
         format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")[1]
# [1] "2014-02-11 04:19:39"
```